# Flutter Firebase Iterate through all documents that matches field value and inserting field from each one into a List of String

Tags: flutter, firebase, dart, google-cloud-firestore

I'm trying to get afield value into a list of string from documents in the firebase that match the WHERE of a field value from a value of my own.
(I wanna show images above each other to create a full picture depending on the data, using two fields to be exact and then creating a list of images to show as positioned inside a Stack)
my code:
Implant Class:

```
class Implant {
  final String id;
  final String pid;
  final String aptid;
  late String type;
  late double? sizew;
  late int? sizel;
  late String? positionQ;
  late int? positionN;

  Implant(this.id, this.pid, this.aptid, this.type, this.sizew, this.sizel,
      this.positionQ, this.positionN);

  Map<String, dynamic> toJson() => {
        'ID': id,
        'PID': pid,
        'APTID': aptid,
        'TYPE': type,
        'SIZEW': sizew,
        'SIZEL': sizel,
        'POSITIONQ': positionQ,
        'POSITIONN': positionN,
      };

  factory Implant.fromJson(Map<String, dynamic> json) {
    return Implant(
      json['ID'],
      json['PID'],
      json['APTID'],
      json['TYPE'],
      json['SIZEW'],
      json['SIZEL'],
      json['POSITIONQ'],
      json['POSITIONN'],
    );
  }

  static Map<String, dynamic> toMap(Implant implant) => {
        'ID': implant.id,
        'PID': implant.pid,
        'APTID': implant.aptid,
        'TYPE': implant.type,
        'SIZEW': implant.sizew,
        'SIZEL': implant.sizel,
        'POSITIONQ': implant.positionQ,
        'POSITIONN': implant.positionN,
      };
  static String encode(List<Implant> implant) => json.encode(
        implant
            .map<Map<String, dynamic>>((implant) => Implant.toMap(implant))
            .toList(),
      );
  static List<Implant> decode(String implants) =>
      (json.decode(implants) as List<dynamic>)
          .map<Implant>((implant) => Implant.fromJson(implant))
          .toList();
}
```

Future of list of string function:

```
static Future<List<String>> getImplants(Patient patient) async {
    List<String> result = ['assets/images/teeth/empty.png'];
    var collection = FirebaseFirestore.instance.collection('implants');
    var docSnapshot = await collection.doc(patient.id).get();
    if (docSnapshot.exists) {
      Map<String, dynamic> data = docSnapshot.data()!;
      result.add(data['POSITIONQ'] + data['POSITIONN']);
    }
    return result;
  }
```

How I translate them into Stack and Positioned:

```
static Future<void> showPatientImplants(BuildContext context, Patient patient,
      {bool spaces = true}) async {
    List<String> myImplants;
    myImplants = await getImplants(patient);
    List<Widget> x = [Image.asset('assets/images/teeth/empty.png')];
    myImplants.forEach((element) {
      x.add(Image.asset(element));
    });

    return await showDialog(
        context: context,
        builder: (BuildContext context) {
          return AlertDialog(
            scrollable: true,
            content: SingleChildScrollView(
              child: GestureDetector(
                onTap: () {
                  log(myImplants.toString());
                },
                child: Stack(
                  children: x,
                ),
              ),
            ),
          );
        });
  }
```

The only problem I'm facing -I think- is that the Future<List> function doesn't get me the values I need.

I tried using other functions I found on SO and google, nothing worked.
I guess I can try using the stream and Listview.builder just to get the files names but it seems like exactly how it shouldn't be done.
any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Never mind Solved it using the following code:

```
static Future<List<String>> getImplants(Patient patient) async {
    List<String> result = ['assets/images/teeth/empty.png'];
    log('ID:${patient.id}');
    var collection = FirebaseFirestore.instance
        .collection('implants')
        .where('PID', isEqualTo: patient.id);
    var docSnapshot = await collection.get();
    for (var element in docSnapshot.docs) {
      if (element.exists) {
        Map<String, dynamic> data = element.data();
        result.add(data['POSITIONQ'].toString() + data['POSITIONN'].toString());
      }
    }

    return result;
  }
```

but if anyone has a better idea I appreciate it along with everyone who has a similar problem.